# Rails Engine Model Decorator In A Separate Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have an isolated Rails Engine, Gemgento.  It relies on decorators to add functionality to the Application.  This works great, the model/controller decorators just go in /app/decorators/models/gemgento/model_decorator.rb.

However, I have some gems that can be paired with Gemgento and extend it's functionality for specific Magento extensions.  I need to add a Gemgento model decorator in a separate gem.  The gem already requires Gemgento and uses some of it's API models.

How can I decorate an Engine model from a separate gem?

Here's the gem - https://github.com/gemgento/webtex_gift_cards

Normally, in my application, I would write:

```
Gemgento::Order.class_eval do
   def add_to_cart(product, quantity)
      if product.magento_type == 'gift_card'
         GemgentoWebtexGiftCards.add_to_cart(self.magento_quote_id, ....)
      else
         ...
      end
   end
end
```

How can this be done from within the gem?

Comment: no solution ? looking for the same architecture

Comment: No sorry.  Didn't find a solution.  I ended up including the gem specific code in the engine itself.